# Google Chrome fails to launch on Heroku using Cedar-14 stack

Tags: google-chrome, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, buildpack

We use Google **chrome** & **chromedriver** on Heroku for rendering some HTML in a headless browser. This was working previously, but it now fails with the following error.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.4.0-1019-aws x86_64)
```

Troubleshooting this by running google chrome from the command line as follows also fails:

```
~ $ /app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.7)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.7)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.7)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircore.so.1)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircore.so.1)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0)
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to patch heroku xvfb chrome buildpack, not sure if libstdc++6 is really needed as extra package:

```
diff --git a/bin/compile b/bin/compile
index 6d092e9..ead9239 100755
--- a/bin/compile
+++ b/bin/compile
@@ -67,7 +67,7 @@ esac

 indent "Installing Google Chrome from the $channel channel."

-PACKAGES="https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-${channel}_current_amd64.deb libxss1 libnss3 xvfb"
+PACKAGES="libstdc++6 https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-${channel}_current_amd64.deb libxss1 libnss3 xvfb"

 APT_CACHE_DIR="$CACHE_DIR/apt/cache"
 APT_STATE_DIR="$CACHE_DIR/apt/state"
@@ -146,7 +146,8 @@ BIN_DIR=$BUILD_DIR/.apt/usr/bin
 rm $BIN_DIR/$SHIM
 cat <<EOF >$BIN_DIR/$SHIM
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
-exec \$HOME/.apt/opt/google/$BIN --disable-gpu --no-sandbox \$@
+export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
+\$HOME/.apt/opt/google/$BIN --disable-gpu --no-sandbox \$@
 EOF
 chmod +x $BIN_DIR/$SHIM
 cp $BIN_DIR/$SHIM $BIN_DIR/google-chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an issue with the combination of buildpacks and stacks used on Heroku.

The buildpacks track the latest stable version of Chrome, rather than a specific version. It looks like there's no way to lock in the version, so an update of the latest from Chrome could result in chrome failing

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome#channels

Upgrading build pack from `Cedar-14` to `Heroku-16` meant, for us, that `/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` would successfully run chrome again.